# Android: JSON Parsing error because a String contains " "

Tags: android, json

I am trying to Parse some JSON Strings and I have been successful, however there are times when A string throws a quotation mark for example, "size_box": "PO#45836,4587,3PLTS 48"x40"962LBS @ SHIPREADY BTWN 8AM-1PM", "  Im getting the force close error when it reaches 48"x40"962LBS, So my question is, how can I parse a JSON format link if it has special characters?

Comment: Whatever is generating those strings is broken and needs to be fixed by escaping `"` with `\"`. That needs to be done at source - it's almost impossible to fix it afterwards.

Comment: Ahh I see, so this looks like something that needs to be fixed from the server side. Thanks Squonk, could you put up an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is generating those strings is broken and needs to be fixed by escaping `"` with `\"`.

That needs to be done at source - it's almost impossible to fix it afterwards as you won't be able to tell which quotation marks are meant to be there and which ones (I'm guessing) indicate size of box in inches - 48"x40" is 48 inches x 40 inches correct?

As long as the server escapes those quotation marks, it will parse correctly.

Comment: Just gotta love a down-vote when whoever did it didn't even bother to leave a comment as to why they did it.

Answer (score 0):

Quotation marks `"` should be escaped with a backslash `\` in JSON Strings.

Comment: Wow you are fast on replying! Now this brings up another problem, I will not always know when a string will contain a quotation mark. Is there a way it can be overwritten or something?

Comment: Android has a method for it built-in, [`JSONObject.quote`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Peter, but I have gone another route and decided to just fix it from the server side.

Answer (score -1):

replace the quotes with another character, parse the string, replace the quotes back;

use the function `String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`